# Moving __doPostBack from href to onclick

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, accessibility, asp.net-4.5

If there a way to move the __doPostBack from the href to the onclick? Since this is the default way for asp.net do generate the code.

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$...','DetailRow$3')">...</a>

<a href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$...','DetailRow$3')">...</a>
```

I'm having complaint that screen readers are having a hard with JavaScript in links. Or maybe there's an other way I don't know about to this fix.

If I could I would just to the below example but that's not how the application was built.

```
<a href="somepage.aspx?id=3">...</a>
```

---

I have this when generating LinkButton or sorting of GridView or having a ButtonField type Link in the GridView.

```
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="someButton_Click" ID="someButton" Text="Click here" />

        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="someGridView" AllowSorting="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField SortExpression="SomeField" DataField="SomeField" HeaderText="Sortable Header" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$...','DetailRow$3')">...</a>` should work as you require, what seems to be the issue with it?

Comment: @Jaxi asp.net puts the post back in the href automatically. I wonder if there's a way for the framework to put it in the onclick instead.

Comment: Can you show your code that generates this?

Comment: I can't find a way. I'm starting to think you'll have to use html anchors and manually call `__doPostBack`. Or maybe use a custom attr with the link as a value and "tell" screenreaders to read that attr instead. I don't know if that's even possible.